.NET 6 - Type Agnostic Json Serialization with camelCase through PropertyNamingPolicy
I need a way to read json config via an asp.net 6 backend and send it to frontend in json format with camelCase property names. The original json config uses PascalCasing for its property names. The format of the json is not known by the backend, so there is no possibility for typed object binding.
What I tried, is let ASP.NET bind these parts of the json to either object or JsonElement properties, however that does not seem to work, as the standard serialization options of ASP.NET, which uses camelCasing by default, is not used by JsonElement serializers. This seems very odd and unintended behavior, but has been reported and confirmed as a by-design feature here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61843
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/66661
The first one notes that you can not use JsonElement for this, but should use JsonNode.
The second one notes that also JsonNode does not support this, as by design. This is also confirmed by the official docs.
So how should I provide this functionality with standard System.Text.Json tools? It seems ridiculous to have to write my own converters or use Newtonsoft for conversion for this scenario.
A medium post seems to mention this is possible by using ToJsonString wit serializer options on a JsonObject, but I am unable to replicate this behavior. For me both on .net 6 and .net 8, the naming policy is still ignored and the ToJsonString outputs identical json as what was read from config.
https://medium.com/@serhiikokhan/mastering-the-use-of-system-text-json-e4d37564ab44
Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

As you have noted, this behavior is as designed by MSFT, see the closed issue JsonNode does not respect PropertyNamingPolicy #66661 for confirmation.
As a workaround, you could create a custom JsonConverter<JsonNode> that writes your JsonNode hierarchy using the naming policy specified by JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy like so:
public class NamingPolicyJsonNodeConverter : JsonConverter<JsonNode>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(JsonNode).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert) && !typeof(JsonValue).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonNode? value, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        var namingPolicy = options.PropertyNamingPolicy;
        switch (value)
        {
            case JsonObject obj:
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                foreach (var pair in obj)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(namingPolicy?.ConvertName(pair.Key) ?? pair.Key);
                    Write(writer, pair.Value, options);
                }
                writer.WriteEndObject();
                break;
            case JsonArray array: // We need to handle JsonArray explicitly to ensure that objects inside arrays have their properties renamed
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var item in array)
                    Write(writer, item, options);
                writer.WriteEndArray();
                break;
            case null:
                writer.WriteNullValue();
                break;
            default: // JsonValue
                value.WriteTo(writer, options);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public override JsonNode? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => JsonNode.Parse(ref reader);
}

Then use it when re-serializing your JsonNode hierarchy to remap property names as they are written like so:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new NamingPolicyJsonNodeConverter() },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = true,
};

// Parse or deserialize the JSON using one of the two methods:
// var node = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(inputJson, options);
var node = JsonNode.Parse(inputJson);   

// Then serializing using the specified options + converter to remap property names:
var outputJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(node, options);

Demo .NET 6 fiddle here.

Update
If I have the original config as a Typed deserialize, but it contains objects, these are deseralized automatically as JsonElement. This adds a lot to the ugliness of the whole setup -> dotnetfiddle.net/ec0jxN -> or what do you suggest?
You can set JsonSerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling to JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode to force values declared as object or dynamic to be deserialized as JsonNode types rather than JsonElement.  If you do you will not need to write a converter that handles both types.
Say your original config model looks like:
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}

You can round-trip it from JSON converting the Data nodes to camel case as follows:
var inOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = null,
    UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode,
    AllowTrailingCommas = true,
};
var outOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new NamingPolicyJsonNodeConverter() },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(inputJson, inOptions);

// Serialize using the specified options + converter to remap property names:
var outputJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, outOptions);

Demo fiddle #2 here.
Alternatively, you could create a converter for JsonElement instead of JsonNode:
public class NamingPolicyJsonElementConverter : JsonConverter<JsonElement>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonElement value, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        var namingPolicy = options.PropertyNamingPolicy;
        switch (value.ValueKind)
        {
            case JsonValueKind.Object:
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                foreach (var pair in value.EnumerateObject())
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(namingPolicy?.ConvertName(pair.Name) ?? pair.Name);
                    Write(writer, pair.Value, options);
                }
                writer.WriteEndObject();
                break;
            case JsonValueKind.Array: // We need to handle JsonArray explicitly to ensure that objects inside arrays have their properties renamed
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var item in value.EnumerateArray())
                    Write(writer, item, options);
                writer.WriteEndArray();
                break;
            default: // JsonValue
                value.WriteTo(writer);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public override JsonElement Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(ref reader);
}

And use it as follows:
var inOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = null,
    AllowTrailingCommas = true,
};
var outOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new NamingPolicyJsonElementConverter() },
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    WriteIndented = true,
};

var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(inputJson, inOptions);

// Serialize using the specified options + converter to remap property names:
var outputJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(model, outOptions);

I wouldn't try to handle JsonElement and JsonNode in the same converter, that will just cause confusion.  Use separate converters for each.
Demo fiddle #3 here.
Notes

There is already an open enhancement about this: [API Proposal]: JsonSerializerOptions.JsonObjectKeyPolicy (naming policy) #79624.

The ConvertJsonDocumentToJsonNode() method in your fiddle is not necessary, you can convert between JsonElement and JsonNode in one line by using Deserialize(). See this answer by Guru Stron to Is there a way to convert between JsonDocument and JsonNode?.



Thanks for the suggestion - If I have the original config as a Typed deserialize, but it contains objects, these are deseralized automatically as JsonElement. This adds a lot to the ugliness of the whole setup -> https://dotnetfiddle.net/ec0jxN -> or what do you suggest?
This really feels like the incorrect way of doing things? A JsonSerializer with options can't use those options to serialize the standard json components...
On the suggestion of the JsonNode.Parse, I'd rather use JsonSerializer.Deserialize since JsonNode.Parse doesn't use serializerOptions (can't handle trailing commas).

Thanks a lot! I'm still not convinced this was the best decision for System.Text.Json to ignore serializer options on JsonNode/Element serialization, but with your update I better understand how it works under the hood (didn't know about JsonSerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling) and with your extra suggestions it indeed makes it work for my scenario in an 'ok' way.

@BasiK - I agree that the design of System.Text.Json makes it harder than it should be to do easy things.  JsonSerializerOptions already has PropertyNamingPolicy and DictionaryKeyPolicy, it would be reasonable to open an issue requesting a JsonNodeNamingPolicy or JsonElementNamingPolicy.

@BasiK - seems like there is already an open enhancement related to this: [API Proposal]: JsonSerializerOptions.JsonObjectKeyPolicy (naming policy) #79624.  You could upvote that or add feedback if you like.
